# What majors study both computer and maths?

Tags: masters, mathematics, major

I would like to apply for a Master degree.
I'm looking for a major that study both Computer and Maths.
Can anyone tell me what such major are?

Comment: Computer science is essentially a kind of mathematics, although it doesn't actually _study_ computers.  Also, a lot of fields _use_ computers these days, so it might help if you clarify how you want computers to be involved.  (And how you want math to be involved, for that matter.)

Comment: You could try some areas of applied math or theoretical CS.

Comment: I don't know in which country you are studying. However, in the UK this depends on the university itself and the Msc program they provide. What part of computer science do you like? Is the programming part or other popular topics (e.g., big data, etc.). Also what you want to do after Msc?

Comment: Combinatorics maybe ?

Comment: Also, if you have skills in both computers and math you are pretty much equipped for any sort of scientific research.  You could think about applying your skills to problems in, say, physics, or biology.  Of course you would have to learn those subjects too, but you'd have a nice head start.

Answer (score 3):

As an example, the University of Oxford (UK) as an [MSc program in Mathematics and the Foundations of Computer Science](http://www.ox.ac.uk/admissions/graduate/courses/msc-mathematics-and-foundations-computer-science), which not only has courses in computer science and mathematics, but in particular also offers courses on the interplay between these areas.

Answer (score 2):

If you like applied, Computational Mathematics could be a good option.

Answer (score 2):

Many scientific fields nowadays rely heavily on computation (physics, statistics, biology, etc). You could go into any of these with a computational focus in mind (develop new computational methodology, algorithms, improve speed/performance of existing algorithms).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your prior experience/work is, but if you have a little experience in Computer Science, another option is Cryptography.

Though it's usually not an explicit major, one typically studies it through a given Mathematics program, and if you concentrate on the applied side of things (i.e., writing actual algorithms and performing time/space analyses of them), you'll be deep enough in the weeds to be forced to learn more Computer Science along the way.